# Xcode Dependencies Error

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, cocoapods

I was having an issue changing my Target Deployment to 8.4 (its been 9.1since I started the project). I was getting an error saying Parse was setup to use 9.1 so I couldn't change it. Then I changed the platform information in my podfile and reinstalled the pods. Now I am getting these two errors when I try and Build the app.

> Check dependencies
>
> Unable to run command 'CpResource RLA\ Volunteer.app' - this target might include its own product.
>
> Unable to run command 'Touch RLA\ Volunteer.app' - this target might include its
> own product.

Any help is welcome.

I'm running Xcode 7.1.1 on a Macbook Pro and coding in Swift.

Comment: try doing a deep clean, deleting the Build folder, delete the Pods.lock file and the Pods folder and do a `pod setup` again?

Comment: good thought. getting the exact same errors though

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. My .app file in my Product folder in Xcode had a selected target. I don't really understand why it worked by unselecting a Target Membership (so nothing is selected when I select the .app file) fixed the dependency errors.